# Is it possible to replace clients cached file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I know we can use `cache-control expires pragma` in the `meta` tag to disable users caching the file. However, I forget these tags when I publish the file in the first place. Now some people has open this page. Even now I added these tags, it doesn't affect these users.

One way I can think of is to change the name of my `html, css, js` files. But it will take a lot of time. Is there any easier way?

Comment: why will change the name of static files take a lot of time?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "?" and some key-value pair like "v=1.01" to the end of the file extensions like .css and .js within your HTML.

For example:

```
<script src="https://www.yoursite.com/assets/scripts.min.js?v=1.01"></script>
```

This helps grab the newest version of that script/stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you. So I just need to change the `script` and `style` tag in the `html` file? Is the query arbitrary and I don't need to do anything for my `js` file with is `v`?

Comment: Correct. You can also edit the .htaccess file and disable caching that way as well. I don't know which way is best however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I do not have access to the server, that's why I would like to do so in the client side.